# Count with unions

Tags: sql, oracle, count, union, parentheses

With this code:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM pcpedc WHERE pcpedc.numped IN (
  SELECT numped FROM pcpedc
  WHERE pcpedc.DATA = TO_DATE('15-MAR-2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND pcpedc.hora < 16
  AND pcpedc.posicao = 'L'
  AND pcpedc.dtinicialcheckout IS NULL
  AND pcpedc.horalibera IS NULL

  UNION

  SELECT numped FROM pcpedc WHERE pcpedc.DATA < TO_DATE('15-MAR-2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND pcpedc.posicao = 'L'
  AND pcpedc.dtinicialcheckout IS NULL

  UNION

  SELECT numped FROM pcpedc WHERE pcpedc.DATA = TO_DATE('15-MAR-2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND pcpedc.hora < 16
  AND pcpedc.posicao = 'L'
  AND pcpedc.dtinicialcheckout IS NULL)
```

A got an error relating to parenthesis, like this:

14:45:58  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which client are you running this in - SQL\*Plus? If so, what does `show sqlblanklines` report?

Comment: i guess you are missing a `semi-colon` to terminate your statement if you are running it from sqlplus

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with this query.  Perhaps the error is coming from other code.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong, although it's not necessarily going to return what you want with those TO_DATE('15-MAR-2016','DD/MM/YYYY') statements where you have the hard_coded dd-mon-yyyy values being formatted with dd/mm/yyyy !

Comment: Well spotted @Michael Broughton. Once the OP gets over the initial problem (probably by removing the blank lines and/or adding a semicolon), this will be the next ORA exeception they get.

Comment: Thank you all! Even putting the semi-colon in the end, I've got an error, like this: 18:54:43  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, only the hint that you can simplify the query. (Your first query even retrieves a subset of your last one.)

```
select count(distinct numped)
from pcpedc
where posicao = 'L'
and dtinicialcheckout is null
and
(
  (data = date'2016-03-15' and hora < 16 and horalibera is null)
  or 
   data < date'2016-03-15'
);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. I'll try to simplify next time (I'm a beginer in SQL language you hint was very useful)